# TextView number displayed after comma

Tags: android, textview, number-formatting

I'm currently displaying float in my TextView, but there are 8 numbers after comma which are displayed. It's quite annoying to have that much numbers. I don't wanna change my TextView width. Does anyone know how I can chose how many numbers after comma to display? Or how I can round the float properly to get 1 number after the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found something nice :
If you have a string which contain a number

```
String numberLambda = "1980507120.9475";
```

You can use the DecimalFormat class

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.0");
```

That defines how to display NUMBERS.

Now you can turn your string into a number to use the formatter on it by this way :

```
double stringIntoNumber = Double.parseDouble(numberLambda);
```

And you can add it again to a string to display it in your TextView!

```
String newNumber = "Value formatted :" + formatter.format(numberLambda);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String Formatter. see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

For Example if you want to limit a int  to 2 digit and convert to string you can do following

```
String s = String.format("%2d",name);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't wanna just chose the number of digit, i wanna chose the number before coma and after precisely ! But Thanks StinePike!

Comment: are you using two different number? before and after comma?

Comment: it's a single float like float : 147,94751
But as you see, number before and after coma are different